# Reactjs protected routes [Guard] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm new on ReactJS. I follow this[tutorial](https://medium.com/technology-hits/laravel-react-fullstack-application-with-passport-redux-and-material-ui-frontend-5c39cf6d7ba4) but I got error with my Router

There is my app.js

```
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import MyRoutes from "./MyRoutes";
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="App">
        <MyRoutes/>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
 );
}
export default App;
```

My MyRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes,Route,Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from "./components/pages/HomeComponent";
import Login from "./components/pages/LoginComponent";
import Register from "./components/pages/RegisterComponent";
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import {Guard} from './Guard';
import Header from './components/layouts/Header';
function MyRoutes(){
  return (
    <>
        <Header/>
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" render={props => (
                <Navigate to={{ pathname: '/home' }} />
            )}/>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path="/user/login" element={<Login/>}/>
            <Route path="/user/register" element={<Register/>}/>
            {/*Redirect if not authenticated */}
            <Route element={<Guard path="/user" token="user-token" routeRedirect="/user/login" element={<PrivateRoute/>} />} />
        </Routes>
    </>
);
}
export default MyRoutes;
```

My Guard.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Navigate, Outlet} from 'react-router-dom';
export const Guard = ({component:Component, token:Token, routeRedirect,...rest}) => (
<Route {...rest} render={props => (
    localStorage.getItem(Token) ?
        <Outlet/> :
        <Navigate to={{pathname:routeRedirect, state:{from:props.location}}} />
)}/>
);
```

And my PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Routes ,Route,Navigate} from 'react-router-dom';
import Profile from './components/pages/ProfileComponent';
export default function PrivateRoute(props) {
return (
    <div>
        {/*<Header/>*/}
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path={`${props.match.path}/view-profile`} element={<Profile/>}/>
            <Route exact path={props.match.path} render={props=> (
                <Navigate to={{ pathname: `${props.match.path}/view-profile` }} />
            )} />
        </Routes>
    </div>
);
}
```

And I got this error : " [Guard] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>"

I do some research and read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou) but I don't understand how to solve my issue

Could you help me please ?

I use React v17.0.2, react-router v6.2.2 and react-router-dom v6.2.2

Comment: What isn't clear about the error? `Guard` component isn't a `Route` or `React.Fragment` so it can't be rendered by a `Routes` component. It seems you are asking several questions: (1) how to upgrade from RRDv5 to RRDv6, (2) How to create a private route component, and (3) the error. Have you followed the [v5/v6 migration guide](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5)?

Comment: I understood this error but I don't know how to solve this. The migration guide doesn't explain how to do this

Comment: Please try following the upgrade guide to first resolve all the route issues first... then after those are fixed and you've *only* the route protection remaining we can help with that specific issue. In case it's not clear, the RRDv6 routes use only an `element` prop for their routed components.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese, I updated my post with new code (element prop) but I don't understand how to get routes from PrivateRoute and Guard components

Comment: Because only Guard check if token exist and then, get routes from PrivateRoute. Also with Guard we can prefix our routes (here, it's only "user" ("user/view-profile") but after, I can do this with new prefix like "store" and redirect ton another route

Comment: Okay so I updated my MyRoutes.js and Guard.js (look at my post) but I don't understand how to get Path in PrivateRoute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The `Guard` component is still trying to directly render a `Route` component, which is invalid in `react-router-dom@6`. It just needs to render the `Outlet` or redirect.

All `Route` components use the `element` prop that takes a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. There are no longer any `component` or `render` and `children` function props.

Nest the one `"/user/view-profile"` route that `PrivateRoute` was rendering directly in the `Guard` layout route.

## Example Solution

```
export const Guard = ({ token, routeRedirect }) => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return localStorage.getItem(token)
    ? <Outlet/>
    : <Navigate to={routeRedirect} replace state={{ from: location }} />;
};
```

Usage:

```
function MyRoutes() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}/>
        <Route path="/user/login" element={<Login />}/>
        <Route path="/user/register" element={<Register />}/>
        
        <Route
          element={<Guard token="user-token" routeRedirect="/user/login" />}
        >
          <Route path="/user/view-profile" element={<Profile />} />
        </Route>
        ... any other protected routes ...
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}
```