# React 18 | How to make the guard work properly?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get the guard working, following the solution I found to this question:

[Error: [PrivateRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou)

But I get this error:
`A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>.`  Anyone know how to fix it?

Below is my code in App.js whitout imports:

```
//all imports

function PrivateRoute({ element, ...rest }) {
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem('token'); 
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      element={isAuthenticated ? element : <Navigate to="/products" />} 
    />
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Router>
          <Fragment>
            <MainTemplate />
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path='/' element={<Login />} />
              <Route exact path='/products' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/products' element={<Products />} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/product/:id' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/product/:id' element={<Product />} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/add-product' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/add-product' element={<AddProduct />} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/edit-product/:id' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/edit-product/:id' element={<UpdateProduct />} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/orders' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/orders' element={<Orders />} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/edit-order/:id' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/edit-order/:id' element={<UpdateOrder />} />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path='/:category' element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                <Route exact path='/:category' element={<Category />} />
              </Route>
            </Routes>
          </Fragment>
        </Router>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks to whoever will answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reactjs protected routes \[Guard\] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471819/reactjs-protected-routes-guard-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-child)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should refactor your code into a simplified version and more readable. I checked the link you have provided at the top and inside that solution is the version he/she was referering to. Please find it below and I think it will help you fix the problem and simplify your code a little bit.

link (https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove nested `Route` components. If you want some path to be private, then just use your `PrivateRoute` realisation instead of native `Route`.

```
<Routes>
  <Route exact path='/' element={<Login />} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/products' element={<Products />} />
  <PrivateRoute exact path='/product/:id' element={<Product />} />
</Routes>
```

`PrivateRoute` should check if user has access to certain page, and if so return native `Route` with right component.

**Basic `PrivateRoute` component**

```
const PrivateRoute = (props) => {
  const user = somehowGetUserInfo();
  
  if (!user.isLoggedIn) {
    return <div>This page is private, please log in</div>;
  }
  
  return <Route {...props} />
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Route not properly. maybe following solutions would be helpful :

1. You are declaring two components to be render when your website get loaded i.e
    as well as . You may enhance it by using

   <Route exact path='/login' element={} />
   <Route exact path='/' element={} />
2. You may refactor your code and following youtube video may help you :
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul3y1LXxzdU&t=184s