# Route element not getting rendered in router element in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am building a simple application using React Router. Here is the code which I currently have:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />}></Route>
            <MyRoute />
        </Routes>
    )
}

const MyRoute = (props) => {
    return <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}/>
}

export default App
```

Whenever I do this I am getting the following error:

```
utils.ts:757 Uncaught Error: [ProtectedRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
at invariant (utils.ts:757:1)
at components.tsx:563:1
at react.development.js:1195:1
at react.development.js:1158:1
at mapIntoArray (react.development.js:1049:1)
at mapIntoArray (react.development.js:1099:1)
at mapChildren (react.development.js:1157:1)
at Object.forEachChildren [as forEach] (react.development.js:1194:1)
at createRoutesFromChildren (components.tsx:547:1)
at Routes (components.tsx:379:1)
```

But if I return the actual Route component then there is no error. My doubt is that why isn't this working even when I am returning a `Route` element from `MyRoute`?

Please comment if more information is needed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the intended behavior of `react-router` v6 (see [official FAQ](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#route-doesnt-render-how-do-i-compose)).

Your logic should be handled through the `element`. For example, to implement the concept of`ProtectedRoute`, you can do:

```js
const ProtectedRoute = ({ isConnected }) => {
  if (!isConnected) {
    return <Navigate to="/landing" replace />;
  }

  return <Outlet />;
};

function App() {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path='/Login' element={<Login />}></Route>
            <Route element={<ProtectedRoute isConnected={...} />}>
                <Route path='/Dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}/>
                <Route path='/OtherPrivateStuff' element={<OtherPrivateStuff />}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    )
}

export default App
```

The `<Outlet />` component here will get the matching route among the children of the container route.

Source: [React Router 6: Private Routes (alias Protected Routes)](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-private-routes/)