# Uncaught error: [PublicRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, routes, create-react-app

I want to implement `<PublicRoute>` component, inside `<Routes>` but the following error keeps occurring:

> Uncaught error: [PublicRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or <React.Fragment>

Dependencies: "react": "^18.2.0",
"react-router": "^6.4.3"

App.js

```
import React from 'react';

import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
import './styles/main.scss';
import { Routes } from 'react-router';
import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import PublicRoute from './components/PublicRoute';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <PublicRoute path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
      <PrivateRoute path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

PublicRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router';

function PublicRoute({ children, ...routeProps }) {
  const profile = false;

  if (profile) {
    return <Navigate to="/" />;
  }

  return <Route {...routeProps}>{children}</Route>;
}

export default PublicRoute;
```

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I've been trying to render data on webpage. And as per the update, the `<Switch>` has been changed to `<Routes>` but the issue is, the data inside the `<Route>` is not being rendered on the webpage.
Can someone point out the cause/error regarding this?

I've also tried the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou)

```
 <Routes>
  <Route exact path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Route>
  <Route exact path="/signin" element={<PublicRoute />}>
    <Route exact path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

After implementing this solution, I get different error:

Uncaught Error: A `<Route>` is only ever to be used as the child of `<Routes>` element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your `<Route>` in a `<Routes>`.

I encapsulated the `<Route>` in PublicRoute.js, inside the `<Routes></Routes>` and thanks to that the error resolved.

```
 return (
    <Routes>
      <Route {...routeProps}>{children}</Route>
    </Routes>
  );
```

But still, the data is not showing and there's a warning in console instead :

> You rendered descendant `<Routes>` (or called `useRoutes()`) at
> "/signin" (under `<Route path="/signin">`) but the parent route path has
> no trailing "*". This means if you navigate deeper, the parent won't
> match anymore and therefore the child routes will never render.
> Please change the parent `<Route path="/signin">` to `<Route path="/signin/*">`.

I did the changes as suggested, and now there're no errors or warnings but still the data is not shown on webpage.

Answer (score 1):

```
App.js
 import React from 'react';
 
 import 'rsuite/dist/rsuite.min.css';
 import './styles/main.scss';
 import SignIn from './pages/SignIn';
 import Home from './pages/Home';
 import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';
 import PublicRoute from './components/PublicRoute';
 import { Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'

 
 function App() {
 return (
     <Routes>
       <Route exact path="/signIn" element={<SignIn />} />
       <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home />} />
     </Routes>
   ); 
}

 export default App;
```

Comment: I'm able to render data using `<Route>` as you've done in your answer. My Question is how should I implement the `<PublicRoute>` and `<PrivateRoute>` so that data is rendered while logic is intact.

Comment: Try this:  In App.js: <Route exact path="/signIn" element={< PrivateRoute />} /> and in PrivateRoute:  <Routes>
      <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} /> </Routes>

Comment: You may also try this with props:
    In App.js: 
return (      
      <PublicRoute  home= {home}/>
   );  
 In PublicRoute.js: 
 return (
 <Routes>
<Route exact path="/signin" element= {<home />} />
 </Routes> );