# How to fix this error [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following route structure:

```
const CustomRoute = ({ Component, path, url }) => {
  if (!document.referrer.length) {
    return <Navigate to={url} />;
  }
  return <Route path={path} element={<Component />} />;
};


<Router basename={config.historyBasename}>
  <Routes>
    <CustomRoute
      Component={Activate}
      url={routes.landingPage}
      path={routes.userActive}
    />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Here I am using it like this. But I am getting an error. So, How can I fix this?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Error: \[PrivateRoute\] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou). Basically custom route components are no longer allowed as direct children of `<routes/>` in v6, but there are alternate approaches that are still relatively elegant-- check that link for more details.