# Private route with createBrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router-dom

So I'm trying to do make a `SecureRoute` component as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69869761/3006011) (they call it `PrivateRoute`). I'd like to use the [createBrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router) function in index.js. The problem is that the *child* of DashboardPresenter, so the DashboardView that is, when wrapped in SecureRoute does not render. Some imports omitted below for brevity.

index.js:

```
import SecureRoute from "./utils/SecureRoute";
import SecurityProvider from "./utils/SecurityProvider";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider} from "react-router-dom";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorView />,
  },
  {
    path: "/signup",
    element: <SignUpPresenter />,
    errorElement: <ErrorView />,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    element: <LogInPresenter />,
    errorElement: <ErrorView />,
  },
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    element: (
      <SecureRoute>
        <DashboardPresenter /> //Could this be the problem?
      </SecureRoute>
    ),
    errorElement: <ErrorView />,
  },
]);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <SecurityProvider>
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </SecurityProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

SecureRoute:

```
import React from "react";
import LogInPresenter from "../presenters/LogInPresenter";
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import useSecurity from "./useSecurity";

const SecureRoute = () => {
  const { loggedIn } = useSecurity();
  return loggedIn ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="login" />;
};

export default SecureRoute;
```

useSecurity:

```
import { React, useContext } from "react";
import SecurityContext from "./SecurityContext";

const useSecurity = () => useContext(SecurityContext);

export default useSecurity;
```

SecurityContext:

```
import React from "react";
const SecurityContext = React.createContext({});
export default SecurityContext;
```

SecurityProvider:

```
import { React } from "react";
import SecurityContext from "./SecurityContext";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const SecurityProvider = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const {
    //We could use the current data in redux if we had a need for it in the view.
    data: results,
    error,
    loading,
  } = useSelector((state) => state.user || {});
  return (
    <SecurityContext.Provider
      value={{
        logIn: (email, password) => {
          dispatch({
            type: "LOGIN",
            payload: { email: email, password: password },
          });
        },
        logOut: () => {
          dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
        },
        signUp: (email, password) => {
          dispatch({
            type: "SIGNUP",
            payload: { email: email, password: password },
          });
        },
        loggedIn: results,
        loading: loading,
        error: error,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </SecurityContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default SecurityProvider;
```

LogInPresenter:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import LogInView from "../views/LogInView";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import useSecurity from "../utils/useSecurity";

function LogInPresenter() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState();
  const [password, setPassword] = useState();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const { logIn, loggedIn, loading, error } = useSecurity();

  function loggedInACB() {
    console.log(`Log the user in with ${email} and ${password}.`);
    logIn(email, password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loggedIn && !error && !loading) {
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
    return () => {};
  }, [loggedIn, error, loading, navigate]);

  return (
    <LogInView
      loggedIn={loggedInACB}
      loading={loading}
      setEmail={setEmail}
      setPassword={setPassword}
    />
  );
}

export default LogInPresenter;
```

DashboardPresenter:

```
import DashboardView from "../views/DashboardView";
import useSecurity from "../utils/useSecurity";

function DashboardPresenter() {
  const { logOut, loggedIn, loading, error } = useSecurity();

  function logOutACB() {
    console.log("Log the user out.");
    logOut();
  }
  return <DashboardView logOut={logOutACB} loading={loading} />;
}

export default DashboardPresenter;
```

Comment: TL;DR `SecureRoute` is a layout route component, not a wrapper component, so it should be rendered as a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#layout-routes).