# Firebase Auth Protected Route: [PrivateRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a protected (private) route in React. If the user has not logged in, they should be redirected to login.

I have an implementation, but I keep running into the above error.

I am using Firebase to deploy my app.

**firebase/auth.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { projectAuth } from './config'
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth'

const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(projectAuth, email, password)
        const user = userCredential.user
        return user
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

const logout = async () => {
    try {
        await signOut(projectAuth)
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export { login, logout, AuthContext, AuthProvider }
```

**components/PrivateRoute.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Route, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { AuthContext } from "../firebase/auth";

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: RouteComponent, ...rest }) => {
    const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={routeProps =>
                !!user ? (
                    <RouteComponent {...routeProps} />
                ) : (
                    <Navigate to="/login" />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

**app.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import OurPhotos from './components/OurPhotos';
import Login from './components/Login';
import {AuthProvider} from './firebase/auth';
import PrivateRoute from './components/PrivateRoute';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <AuthProvider>
        <Routes>
          <PrivateRoute path="/" element={
            <>
              <OurPhotos />
            </>
          } />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </AuthProvider>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried the answer give [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69864165/error-privateroute-is-not-a-route-component-all-component-children-of-rou) as well, but no luck.