# All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> when <Navigate> is used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have simple React project with next hierarchy of components:

Main component(here I call routing service and render components in a routes):

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
    return <BaseLayout>{RoutingService.getRoutes()}</BaseLayout>;
}

export default App;
```

Code of routing service:

```
class RoutingService {
    static getRoutes = (): React.ReactNode => {
        return (
            <Routes>
                <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.ROOT_PATH} element={<MainPage/>}/>
                <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.AUTH_PATH} element={<LoginPage/>}/>
                <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.NOT_FOUND_PATH} element={<UnderConstructPage/>}/>
                <ProtectedRoute path={PATHS.SEARCH_HISTORY_PATH} element={<SearchHistoryPage/>}/>
                <ProtectedRoute path={PATHS.USER_CABINET_PATH} element={<UserCabinetPage/>}/>
            </Routes>
        );
    };
}

export default RoutingService;
```

So what I want to perform - to have some opened routes(pages) for all users(logged in and non-logged in) like main page, not found and auth pages.
But I have pages where I need to restrict access for non-logged users. for that purpose I created ProtectedRoute component which should redirect user to auth page when he isn't logged in and tries to access pages which require login.

```
interface ProtectedRouteProps {
    path: string;
    element: React.ReactNode;
}

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = ({path, element}) => {
    const isAuthenticated: boolean = useSelector((state: RootState) => !!state.user.userData?.auth?.token);

    return isAuthenticated ?
        <Route path={path} element={element}/> : <> <Navigate to="/auth" replace/></> ;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting error:

```
router.ts:5 Uncaught Error: [ProtectedRoute] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>
    at invariant (router.ts:5:1)
```

Seems `<Navigate>` in `ProtectedRoute` component provokes this error, but I don't know, how to implement this redirect correctly. How to fix that?

Comment: Have you seen: [Error: \[PrivateRoute\] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69869761)

Comment: Also the [auth example](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples/auth) provided by the react router dom team?

Comment: Don't use random React keys on components, it will unnecessarily remount them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let try the code:

In RoutingService.tsx

```
            <Routes>
                <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.ROOT_PATH} element={<MainPage />} />
                <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.AUTH_PATH} element={<LoginPage />} />
                <Route element={<ProtectedRoute />}> 
                    <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.SEARCH_HISTORY_PATH} element={<SearchHistoryPage />} />
                    <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.USER_CABINET_PATH} element={<UserCabinetPage />} />
                </Route>
                <Route key={makeRandomKey()} path={PATHS.NOT_FOUND_PATH} element={<UnderConstructPage />} /> // not found should at end line
            </Routes>
```

In ProtectedRoute.tsx

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

interface ProtectedRouteProps {}

const ProtectedRoute: React.FC<ProtectedRouteProps> = () => {
    const isAuthenticated: boolean = useSelector((state: RootState) => !!state.user.userData?.auth?.token);

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to="/auth" replace />;
    }

    return <Outlet />; // This is SearchHistoryPage, UserCabinetPage 
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```